# file region locking using bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying write some script with which i can try to lock a region of file using bash shell script.

I have used flock, but it locks the whole file and does not provide parameters to lock a region of a file like in C language you get with fcntl.

Will be helpful someone can provide some suggestions in this area?

Comment: I dare to say your use-case is starting to look too complex for bash.

Answer (score 1):

As you use flock (1) (which is a C program, see http://util-linux.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.17/flock_8c-source.html) to utilize flock (2), you would need a similar command that utilizes fcntl. If such a command doesn't exist yet, one would have to write it.